# How can I reopen a file stream and emptying it without the filename?

Tags: c, fopen, freopen

Let's say I have a file stream.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("hi.txt", "w");
fprintf(fp, "test");
```

I want to somehow open it again, but I want to also empty it and I don't have access to the filename this time. I tried to do the following, but it doesn't seem to change the output.

```
fp = freopen(NULL, "w", fp);
fprintf(fp, "changed");
fflush(fp);
```

It still says "test" in the output file.

Comment: Weird, works on my machine.

Comment: @Alexguitar: That is the problem with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Did you close it already?

Comment: @texasbruce: No, I left it open.

Comment: Guessing freopen may have certain limitations depending on the library implementation, which is weird, because there's no mention of that in the man pages on my system, although on the c++ reference there is

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  The basic idea is to get the file descriptor from the stream, but you still need to close the stream, so I dup the file descriptor, cleanly close the stream, then call ftruncate on the duplicate file descriptor, bypassing the stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    FILE   *fp;
    int     fd;
    int     fd2;

    fp = fopen("junk.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "foo\n");
    fd = fileno(fp);
    fd2 = dup(fd);
    fclose(fp);
    ftruncate(fd2, 0);
    close(fd2);
    return 0;
}
```